# NSImageView within NSScrollView downward drift

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview, nsimageview, magnification, drift

I have a NSScrollView with a NSImageVIew within.

I'm using magnification enabled on NSScrollView.

I'm seeing a funny downward drift of the NSImageView when scaling using a 'pinch' gesture on my MBP track pad.

If you pinch and un-pinch continuously ... zooming in and out, the image drifts downwards within the NSScrollView. Can't explain it or locate bug.

See here > https://github.com/BinaryBlobs/ScrollViewBug

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Just happened to me. Did you find anything about this?

Comment: Let me checkout what I did - but I think it was rebuilding the XIB file.